# Getting below error while building hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Running below command to build hyperledger after some time I see below error in my terminal

```
$ make dist-clean all

build/bin/peer
CGO_CFLAGS=" " GOBIN=/usr/share/go-1.6/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build/bin go install -ldflags "-X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.Version=0.7.0-snapshot-29d7fc0 -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.BaseVersion=0.3.0 -X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/metadata.BaseDockerLabel=org.hyperledger.fabric" github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
/usr/lib/go-1.6/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/ccproviderimpl.go:20:2: cannot find package "context" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/context (vendor tree)
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/vendor/context
    /usr/share/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/context
    /usr/share/go/src/vendor/context
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/context (from $GOROOT)
    /usr/share/go/src/context (from $GOPATH)
Makefile:177: recipe for target 'build/bin/peer' failed
make: *** [build/bin/peer] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to build and test the fabric that you will need to provide some context for this question to have any chance of being answered.

However, to short-circuit the process, allow me to offer a couple of useful documents that should be read before attempting to work with the latest fabric code:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/source/install_instantiate.rst

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/source/dev-setup/build.rst

Comment: I am trying to build hyperledger fabric from source code. I am able to install fabric without source code using docker.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with this: [#23672](http://The%20problem%20has%20to%20do%20with%20this:%20#23672%20It%20affects%20Go%20versions%201.8.7,%201.9.4%20and%201.10rc2)
It affects Go versions 1.8.7, 1.9.4 and 1.10rc2

I downgraded the golang version from 1.9.4 to 1.9 which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Update your golang version, 1.7.0+ may be helpful.